# .net framework 3 provide xsd unique element?

Tags: .net, xsd

I must use unique element like ;

```
<xsd:key name="GlobalPackageNameKey">
  <xsd:selector xpath=".//ns:Package"/>
  <xsd:field xpath="@Name"/>
</xsd:key>
```

any idea if .net framework 3.0 provide this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, all of these are fully supported by .NET framework, both from an [XML Schema processing API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.schema.xmlschemaidentityconstraint.aspx) as well as XML document validation.